# Generic props in react/typescript - how to get T to be the type of a property?

Tags: typescript

I've tried countless things but couldn't get this to work

I have props for a react component, and the type of `handleChange` should be a function that takes in whatever was passed as `values`.

```
type Props<T extends Record<string, unknown> = Record<string, unknown>> = {
   value: T,
   handleChange: (value: T) => void
}
```

I'm trying to get T to be "the type of `value`", but in this example they are just defaulted to `Record` which is not what i want,.

This is done excessively in material ui (i.e. autocomplete)

Comment: You set a default and it used the default. I'm not sure what you expected. If you added the default because you don't want to have to specify the generic type, i.e. you want it inferred from the type of `value`, have a generic in the actual function or class that extends `Record<string, unknown>` and forward it to the generic parameter of `Props`, removing all defaults.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I didnt expect my example to work, I'm just trying to show what I've tried. You're right in that I want it inferred, but all examples I've seen are trying to differentiate between specific known types like `TypeA | TypeB`, but I'm trying to infer whatever is passed in as long as its a Record. I'm having issues wrapping my head around doing that.

Comment: So I think I dont understand what the "actual class" that extends `Record<string, unknown>` has to be. How do I create such a class to forward a generic or how do I find out about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript has a powerful inference system, which allows you to not specify the generic parameter manually but rather have it assigned based on the type of a runtime parameter. For React + TypeScript, this looks like:

```
type MyComponentProps<T extends Record<string, unknown>> = {
  value: T;
  handleChange: (value: T) => void;
};

const MyComponent = <T extends Record<string, unknown>>(
  props: MyComponentProps<T>
) => {
  return null;
};

class MyOtherComponent<
  T extends Record<string, unknown>
> extends React.Component<MyComponentProps<T>> {
  render() {
    return null;
  }
}
// This works
<MyComponent
  value={{ a: "hi", this: { is: "a", test: true } }}
  handleChange={(val) => {
    console.log("val.a =", val.a, "val.this =", val.this);
  }}
/>
<MyOtherComponent
  value={{ a: "hi", this: { is: "a", test: true } }}
  handleChange={(val) => {
    val.a = val.this.is;
  }}
/>
// This fails
<MyComponent
  value="not a Record<string, unknown>"
  handleChange={() => {}}
/>
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-wave-oevwj?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: It works! Awesome. Just a little thing, is there a way to make this work with this notation? `const MyComponent: React.FC<P<T>> = <T extends Record<string, unknown>>() => ...`?

Comment: No, that isn't possible. You can't use a generic declared in an anonymous function to type the variable that contains it. The type of `MyComponent` is compatible with the `React.FC<MyComponentProps<T>>` type you want, so theoretically you shouldn't need to worry about it. In the worst case scenario, you can always cast.